Converting between calendars in SQL
I am trying to convert calendar dates (jan-jan) into dates based on the (april-april) calendar.
Basically what I am trying to do is this:

Start with a date in this format full_date = 2020-12-12
Identify the week number relative to the january calendar
Identify the year, month, week number (i.e. relative to the april-april calendar)
Only select rows where column 1 is a number or decimal number

Normally I work with Python and this would not be too much of a problem. But I am trying to do this with SQL.
I tried to piece together this code:
SELECT 
    full_date,    
EXTRACT(WEEK FROM full_date) AS jan_calendar_week,

    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) <= 3 THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) + 9
        ELSE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) - 3
    END AS april_calendar_month,
    

    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) <= 3 
        THEN (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) - 1) || '-' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date)
        ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) || '-' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) + 1)
    END AS april_calendar_year,

    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM full_date) <= 3 
        THEN CEIL((full_date - DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) - 1 || '-04-01')) / 7.0)
        ELSE CEIL((full_date - DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM full_date) || '-04-01')) / 7.0)
    END AS april_calendar_week_number
FROM t;

WHERE regexp_like(col1, '^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$');

Is this the correct logic? Are there easier ways to do this using pre-defined functions?

CREATE TABLE t(
    full_date DATE,
    col1 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO t (full_date, col1) VALUES
    ('2023-03-31', '100.50'), 
    ('2023-04-01', '200.75'),  
    
    ('2023-01-15', '300.25'),  
    ('2023-07-01', '400.00'),  
    
    ('2023-05-01', 'ABC'),     
    ('2023-06-01', '500'); 


Show us some sample table data and also its expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

full_date is a DATE variable data type

there is now a minimal reproducible example

What is your desired result?

You forgot the expected result part of the [mcve]. It might be obvious to you, but I don't know what the april-april calendar dates are.

Jan-Jan and Apr-Apr are 13 months each. Do you mean Jan 1-Dec 31 and Apr 1-Mar 31?
